# Java TreeMap single creation

Tags: java, treemap

I have this application that requires the creation of TreeMap<>() and this map only requires to be created once. I have the code to create the map and it works. I also have working methods to save and load the map. I was wondering what is the best way to create the map only once behind the scenes and store it before I run the application for the first time and only this once? I don't want to create a button that says "create map" and then never visit that page again. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it in a static field. This will be created only once and if you call load on it in a static block, it is called only once.

e.g.

```
public static final MyTreeMapWrapper map = new MyTreeMapWrapper();

class MyTreeMapWrapper {
   final TreeMap treeMap = ...

   MyTreeMapWrapper() {
        // loads data into treeMap
```

Comment: Ok but what am asking is, where can I make the call to the method which creates the map? Should I define a new class? a JSF page (because am developing JSF app)? or where else? Any code illustration or psuedo is appreciated :)

Comment: where?is a tricky question.You should know the first call on the page will be directed to some facesconfig.xml file where the class resides.You can try it there

Answer (score 1):

The following class will instanciate the map during the first call to its get method. You just need to call `Bla.getMap()` everytime you need the map, without worrying about its initialization.

```
public class Bla {
    private static TreeMap map = null;
    public static TreeMap getMap() {
        if (map==null) {
            synchronized (Bla.class) {
                map = new TreeMap...
               // rest of initialization code
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```